# What is the right permissions to set for /war/www/mywebsite folder permissions, apache user and group of developers

Tags: linux, apache, file-permissions, acl

I have a question about the right approach for */var/www/somesite* folder permissions.
The story is like this.
I have 5 developers, I put them all as members of `devteam` group
I have the website folder `/var/www/mywebsite` and I know that `/var/www/mywebsite/info` folder rquires apache to write into it. I'm using ACLs because I believe that's the best approach to control what I'm looking for.

So... I configured the whole thing like this:

The structure:

```
joel@server:$ ls -la /var | grep www
drwxrwxr--+  3 www-data www-data 4096 Jul 11 01:12 www
joel@server:$

joel@server:$ ls -la /var/www
drwxrwxr--+  3 www-data www-data 4096 Jul 11 01:12 .
drwxr-xr-x  15 root     root     4096 Jul 11 14:37 ..
dr-xrwsr--+ 16 www-data www-data 4096 Jul 12 06:49 mywebsite
joel@server:$
```

You can see that `setgid` is set on `mywebsite` so that it'll make all executables to run with the privileges of the group

for /var/www

```
joel@server:~$ sudo getfacl -p /var/www
# file: /var/www
# owner: www-data
# group: www-data
user::rwx
user:www-data:r-x
group::r-x
group:www-data:rwx
group:devteam:rwx
mask::rwx
other::r--
```

for /var/www/mywebsite

```
joel@server:~$ sudo getfacl -p /var/www/mywebsite
# file: /var/www/mywebsite
# owner: www-data
# group: www-data
# flags: -s-
user::r-x
user:www-data:r-x
group::r-x
group:www-data:rwx
group:devteam:rwx
mask::rwx
other::r--
```

for /var/www/mywebsite/info

```
joel@server:~$ sudo getfacl -p /var/www/mywebsite/info
# file: /var/www/mywebsite/info
# owner: joel
# group: www-data
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
user:www-data:rwx
group::r-x
group:www-data:rwx
mask::rwx
other::r--
```

Now... everything seems to work, except that when one of the developers tries to use `git` on that folder, they get this error:

```
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Since I did run `git init --shared=group` and I know for sure that the directory structure does have .git in it (see structure below), so... I was sure it's permissions.
Once I've added the users to be part of `www-data` group, they were able to run all the git commands they wanted. (it makes sense, since the files in the directory are with `owner: joel group: www-data`).

The structure looks like that:

```
joel@server:~$ ls -la /var/www/mywebsite/
total 107928
dr-xrwsr--+ 16 www-data www-data      4096 Jul 12 06:49 .
drwxrwxr--+  3 www-data www-data      4096 Jul 11 01:12 ..
-rwxrwxr--+  1 joel     www-data       213 Jul 11 01:25 .editorconfig
-rw-rw-r--+  1 joel     www-data      2013 Jul 11 20:48 .env
drwxrwxr-x+  8 joel     www-data      4096 Jul 12 10:55 .git
-rwxrwxr--+  1 joel     www-data       111 Jul 11 01:25 .gitattributes
-rwxrwxr--+  1 joel     www-data       309 Jul 11 01:25 .gitignore
-rwxrwxr--+  1 joel     www-data       412 Jul 11 21:00 .htaccess
-rwxrwxr--+  1 joel     www-data       174 Jul 11 01:25 .styleci.yml
drwxrwsr--+ 12 joel     www-data      4096 Jul 11 01:25 helper
-rwxrwxr--+  1 joel     www-data      1686 Jul 11 01:25 mainly
-rw-rw-r--+  1 joel     www-data      1304 Jul 11 01:25 pipelines.yml
drwxrwsr--+  3 joel     www-data      4096 Jul 11 01:25 info
-rwxrwxr--+  1 joel     www-data       707 Jul 11 01:25 story.php
-rwxrwxr--+  1 joel     www-data      2069 Jul 11 09:50 offset.json
```

The reason it's me as the owner of everything, is because I was the one who pulled it from the repository to begin with, but, it'll probably change since these developers will pull the stuff they need while logging in with their credentials, and, it'll change.

On to my questions:

1. Is this the right approach to the order and structure of the website?
2. I don't want my developers to be part of `www-data` group because, well, because that group is not for them! it's for apache to run the server. What can I do? How can I set it up currectly so that they'll be able to work git without being part of the `www-data` group? (I thought about chaning the ownership of the whole website to be owned by the `devteam` group, but, what will happened with `apache2` service then?)
3. How come my `/var/www/mywebsite/info` doesn't have `devteam` permissions in it's ACL (do I really need to set it up for all subfolder if it's already setup for the parent?)
4. Why do I have `mask::rwx` as part oof my ACL configuration? I don't rememebr I set it up.
5. Am I doing the right thing with setting the `setgid` in that way that all my folders are will have the group privileges for executables?

I really appriciate your help on this subject.

Comment: The right approach (TM) is to not give anybody access to your server, but have them go through version control and a controlled deployment process - this way you'll have a chance to restore the server after some failure situation, an audit trail of what software was installed when etc.

Comment: Thanks, Olaf for the respond, and you're right!! but until I get there (because I have no idea what to implement for such small team - and if you have suggestions, please, share) I still need to set it up right

Comment: well - as a minimum: You already have git: Have them commit to the same project, send pullrequests, merge them externally. Then, on your server, at defined times, you (or a script) pull(s) a version that you know is tested and does what you want (e.g. through a tag)

Comment: Maybe I forgot to mention, this machine is a DEVELOPMENT machine. I believe working with deployhq.com on production machine/environment will be better

Comment: I've added that to my answer

Comment: Ok, so....  lets say I do setup NO developers access to my development machine.
If you take that out of the equasion, does the folder configuration makes sense?

Comment: It's irrelevant then. No need for ACLs and fancy multi-account write-permissions.

Answer (score 1):

The right approach (TM) is to not give anybody access to your server, but have them go through version control and a controlled deployment process - this way you'll have a chance to restore the server after some failure situation, an audit trail of what software was installed when etc.

As a minimum, either you or a script might pull a tagged version from a central git repo every now and then. This way it's only you or the script to ever write to Apache's directory. All developers collaborate through git, in a central repository. They send pull requests, and you'll have a trail of who did what when and why.

On the central repository, somebody merges pull requests, tags - and you're set.

Of course - you can go more fancy, but the situation that you describe sounds like a bad workaround for a problem that nobody should have (live write access to a server, for a dev team of >1 size)

Edit: this even holds on a development machine. If hate to make a change and debug why it doesn't work,  only to find out that it's due to somebody else's change, after an hour of useless debugging